# Is it possible to set Form.Width to 10000 pixel?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

When you compile blank form and you try to resize it's width with mouse, it will stop probably, when it's clientwidth is near screen resolution width.

It is not possible set wider form even in designer. (Strange enough, I would never suppose it happens). I also played with Constraints too, but it is no solution either.

Is it possible to set Form.Width to 10000 pixel?

Comment: What happens when you try to do this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it stops widen, when you use mouse. And if you try to put the value 10000 in design time, it will be the highest possible value.

Comment: I don't understand that. I know that the window manager won't let you resize larger than desktop size. But you can set the width programmatically. What happens when you do this? You can answer the question yourself.

Comment: If you try to set the width of form programmatically (Form1.Width := 6000), it will not help. It will be still 1932  (1920x1080)

Comment: I added information from your comment under the accepted answer and removed the duplicate status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Window size is limited by system - you can retrieve this value using function `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMAXTRACK)` - it is 1292 for my 1280x1024 display.

To allow your form be wider, you can treat message [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-getminmaxinfo) providing desired max size:

```
procedure WMGETMINMAXINFO(var M: TWMGetMinMaxInfo); message WM_GETMINMAXINFO;
...
procedure TForm1.WMGETMINMAXINFO(var M: TWMGetMinMaxInfo);
begin
  M.MinMaxInfo.ptMaxTrackSize.X := 5000;
  M.Result := 0;
  inherited;
end;
```

With such message handler I am able to set `Width := 5000;` successfully in runtime.

Normally you should be able to use `Constraints` property of the form and set its `MaxWidth` to achieve this as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35580319/243614) but `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` of `TCustomForm` is defective in Delphi 7. Calling of  `ConstrainedResize` method from the message handler depends on some `FSizeChanging` boolean field, which unfortunately is never set to true. This is corrected and the field is removed somewhere in between D2007 and DXE.

Comment: Brilliant! Works for me too... Thanks

Comment: /To Edit/ No, there is Constraints in D7, and I played with it too, but it is not solution neither. Your answer is correct.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Really? I can set constraints.maxwidth := 10000 but I can not stretch width beyond 2000 by any means.

Comment: I've messed up somehow, it cannot work in D7... Removed my comment.